# Django - Conditionnal filtering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to display the list of the latest articles for each users.

My condition: if a user has bookmarked one of his articles, I want to display the latest bookmarked article for this user ; otherwise I want to display the latest article.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bookmarked = models.BooleanField()
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticlesListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    model = models.Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        articles = self.model.objects.order_by('-date')\
            .filter(pk__in=Article.objects.values('author__id')
            .annotate(
                latest=Case(

                    # Displaying the latest article
                    default=Max('id')
                )
            )
            .values('latest'))
```

In this code I am trying to implement a condition using the [Case expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to check my condition, but I am stuck how to formulate it...

**UPDATE**

Another way: I try to combine querysets

```
class ArticlesListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    model = models.Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        lastest_articles = self.model.objects.order_by('-date')\
            .filter(pk__in=Article.objects.values('author__id')
            .annotate(max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))

        bookmarked_articles = self.model.objects.order_by('-date')\
            .filter(bookmarked=True)

        articles = bookmarked_articles | lastest_articles
```

However, in my final query I get more than one article per author. Can I filter this query to get only one article per user, prioritizing the bookmarked articles?

Answer (score 0):

Using your last query, this might work:

```
latest_articles = self.model.objects.order_by('-date')\
    .filter(pk__in=Article.objects.values('author__id')
    .annotate(max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id'))

bookmarked_articles = self.model.objects.order_by('-date')\
    .filter(bookmarked=True)

articles = bookmarked_articles | latest_articles # OR both together
articles = articles.order_by('-bookmarked')[0:1]      # Select bookmark else latest article
```

For other database backends, use `'bookmarked'` instead (SQLite orders false first).

Comment: I am trying to get the latest_bookmarked for each user.

Comment: Are "author" and "user" the same person?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand better now. What database backend are you using?

Comment: Yes author is a ForeignKey for User. I am using sqlite in dev mode, so no distinct() available.